# parallelized groupby: apply a function to a groupby object simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, performance, for-loop, parallel-processing

I would like to perform a group by operations and for every single group estimate a linear model.

Writing a function and then using a ***for loop is pretty easy*** ,however, kind of slow.

This is a ***toy example*** but it does serve the purpose. What is, in your opinion, the "best" way of making this parallelized?

an intuitive example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import time


# Dataset
df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
df.head()


# Groupby the dataset
df_grouped = df.groupby(["day"])


# Some function to be applied for every grouped element
def regression_model(df):
    """
    This function estimates a linear regression model and returns coefs as dictionary
    """
    model = ols('tip ~ total_bill + C(sex) + size', data = df)
    return dict(model.fit().params)

# Performing the function in the for loop ------ Slow. We want to perform it for each grouped element simultaneously.
coefs_dict = {}

for i, j in df_grouped:
    coefs_i = regression_model(j)
    coefs_dict[i] = coefs_i
    
    # Artificial sleep so we can demostrate that the "mechanical" for loop is slow.... 
    
    time.sleep(2)
```

In this particular case I am using the 'sleep' module to make it slower to demonstrate that the for loop will take a lot of time especially if we would be grouping by much larger number of unique cathegories.

Comment: Look at the multiprocessing package, especially how pools works. I think dask could be useful here too (but I never used so far). Be careful with the sleep test. You way have good result with an approach with it but bad when you will deals with true computation later (due to the GIL, load balancing issues, unsubscription, resource saturation, etc.). A basic loop could be a bit better, and numpy/pandas operations even better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multiprocessing` module as suggested by @JérômeRichard and the `Pool.starmap` to be used with `groupby`

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing


def regression_model(keys, df):
    print(f'Pool: {keys}')
    # do stuff here
    return df


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = []
    with multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
        data = pool.starmap(regression_model, df.groupby('day'))
        df2 = pd.concat(data)
```